# searchbar inside the sidebar in blazor server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, sidebar, searchbar

I have a search bar inside my sidebar.i want the search bar to search through the menu items and the drop down in the way that if the user search for one of the dropdown items and hit enter,it takes them to that page.how can i do that?

this is the code i have now

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <div class="sidebar @((collapsed ? "collapsed" : ""))">
    <nav class="flex-column">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="/img/Boxplosive-logo.png" class="logoimg" /></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="/img/bp-logo-s.png" class="logoimgs" /></a>

            <div class="nav-item px-3">
               
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
             
            </div>


        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sidebar-text"> Dashboard </span>
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3 ">
            <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon oi oi-pencil" aria-hidden="true" href="promotion"></span> <span class="sidebar-text dropright"> Create </span>
            </NavLink>
            @if (expandSubNav)
            {
                    <NavLink class="sidebar-icon expand-menu dropdown-item" href="promotion">
                        <span class="sidebar-text">promotion</span>
                </NavLink>

                    <NavLink class=" sidebar-icon expand-menu dropdown-item " href="loyalty">
                    <span >Loyalty</span>
                </NavLink>
                    <NavLink class=" sidebar-icon expand-menu dropdown-item" href="newsarticle">
                    <span>News Article</span>
                </NavLink>
            }
        </div>

  
          

       
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="publish">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon oi oi-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sidebar-text">Publish</span>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="analyse">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon oi oi-graph" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sidebar-text"> Analyse </span>
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="managment">
                    <span class="sidebar-icon oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sidebar-text"> Managment </span>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="configuration">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon oi oi-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sidebar-text">Configuration</span>
            </NavLink>
        </div>

            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sidebar-text"> Admin </span>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
           
    </nav>
    <nav class="sidebar-footer">

            <button class="sidebar-icon logoutbtn "> <span class="sidebar-text"> Logout </span></button>

            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class=" sidebar-icon logoutbtncollapsed oi oi-account-logout " aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                </NavLink>
            </div>
          


    </nav>
        <button class="collapsebtn oi oi-chevron-left" @onclick="@(() => collapsed = !collapsed)"></button>
    </div>
   
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
    private bool expandSubNav;
    private bool collapsed;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        collapsed = false;
    }





}
```

i tried searching for a solution but it mostly includes js and i dont want that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that you may have to adapt a little to fit with your menu, but it demonstrates the basics of what you need to do.

First a custom `NavLink`, that registers itself with the parent when it first renders.

```cs
@using System.Globalization;
@inherits NavLink
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@_content

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Action<LinkRecord>? Register { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Title { get; set; } = "Not Set";
    [Parameter] public string IconCss { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string TitleCss { get; set; } = "ms-2";

    // Get the base component content
    private RenderFragment _content => (builder) => {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    };

    // this code builds a new ChildContent for the component
    // Add logic if you need more formatting options
    private RenderFragment _childContent => (__builder) =>
    {
        @if(this.IconCss is not null)
        {
            <span class="@IconCss" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        }
        <span class="@TitleCss">@this.Title</span>
    };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        string? href = null;

        if (AdditionalAttributes != null && AdditionalAttributes.TryGetValue("href", out var hrefObj))
            href = Convert.ToString(hrefObj, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var hrefAbsolute = href == null ? null : NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(href).AbsoluteUri;

        if (href is not null && this.Register is not null)
            this.Register(new LinkRecord(this.Title, href));

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Breaks a rule in setting the content of a Parameter
        // but its the only way to feed the content we want to display into the base NavLink component
        this.ChildContent = _childContent;
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

```cs
public record LinkRecord(string Title, string Href);
```

And the standard `NavMenu`

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<CascadingValue Value="this.Register">

    <div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">SO75920338</a>
            <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <nav class="flex-column">
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <MyNavLink Title="Home" IconCss=" oi oi-home" class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                </MyNavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <MyNavLink Title="Counter" IconCss="oi oi-plus" class="nav-link" href="counter">
                </MyNavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <MyNavLink Title="FetchData" IconCss="oi oi-list-rich" class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                </MyNavLink>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="px-2">
            <select class="form-select" @bind:get=this.selectedHref @bind:set=this.OnSelectedChanged>
                @if (selectedHref is null)
                {
                    <option selected disabled value=""> -- Select a Page -- </option>
                }
                @foreach (var link in _links)
                {
                    <option value="@link.Href">@link.Title</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private readonly List<LinkRecord> _links = new();
    private string? selectedHref;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    private void Register(LinkRecord record)
    {
        if (!_links.Any(item => item.Title.Equals(record.Title, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            _links.Add(record);

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void OnSelectedChanged(string value)
    {
        selectedHref = value;
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo(value);
    }
}
```